# Trigger script if there are certain changes before and after a merge on Jenkins

Tags: bash, git, jenkins

I am trying to get Jenkins to trigger a particular script if there is a merge commit to the master branch in which a particular line in a configuration file is changed. Checking for the merge commit on master is easy. The problem is I can't figure out how to check the difference before and after the merge.

I've been trying use `git diff` to do this in the script with an if statement. The best example I've found that seemed close to the correct diff is:

```
git diff -G'changed_field=' HEAD^ HEAD -- config.cfg
```

As it is difficult to see exactly what is going on in Jenkins from the job's console output, all I can figure out is that it is not picking up the change since I'm not seeing any output from this. The diff does work when I run it against my local branch to check my last 2 commits to master.

Answer (score 0):

If HEAD is a merge commit, you could at least do:

```
git show @
# or, more precisely:
git show @:/config.cfg
```

From [git show man page](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-show):

> For commits it shows the log message and textual diff.
>   It also presents the merge commit in a special format as produced by `git diff-tree --cc`.

That will show what was before and what was added/removed as a result of this merge.